# A strange event about duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, duplicates

Recently, [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/895365) was asking to prove two things, say theorem A and theorem B.

Someone proposed to close the question, since there there were another question asking to prove theorem A with an accepted answer.

Someone (me) rejected the proposal, since the OP was asking to prove two things and not just one.

Then someone else proposed to close the question as a duplicate of a question asking to prove theorem B, and such a proposal was successful.

In such peculiar situations, what do you think it is best to do?

Close the OP question as a duplicate of two different questions, merge questions, split questions or what else?

Comment: See [Posting multiple questions as one?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?) We also have a [comment template for that](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/7132#7132).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Isn't the [tag:duplicates] tag a duplicate of [tag:exact-duplicates] tag? I vote to close.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday I have already [suggested a synonym](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/exact-duplicates/synonyms). (And also mentioned this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17113281#17113281).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Upvoted synonym, three more votes needed.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I count two more votes needed. But we already established that comments cannot make a proper replacement for breakfast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to keep separate questions separate, partly so that duplicates can be linked.  The OP **should not** ask two questions in one. If they do, and one of two questions is a duplicate, I will not hesitate to vote to close for that reason. It's up to the OP to split off the question that remains unanswered; the OP is  responsible for the mess, not the close voters.

It is also possible to close as a duplicate of two questions; both will appear in the closure banner. This requires each duplicate target to be chosen by at least one of the voters. Did not happen here, unfortunately. But I went ahead and edited the second link in.

I see no reason to reopen the question.

Comment: I wish the "lollipop" hammer would have the option to close as multiple duplicates. But I don't see this feature being implemented, so I don't bother to post a request.